# How to use Redux Framework for Template Section

Tags: php, wordpress

i need sample wordpress theme all option in the sample-config.php in the template
and how to use all element (ID) sample-config.php in the template .

Home Page this Framework : http://reduxframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Redux Builder: http://build.reduxframework.com. It will give you a customized underscores theme and have Redux fully ready to go.  ;)